# Irvine assembly: How to apply a 3x3 Median Filter on an image using assembly language?

Tags: c#, assembly, x86, masm32

I have read the image using C# windows forms and successfully converted the bitmap into a 1D integer array to pass it as a parameter for the assembly function that's going to do the Median Filter Logic, i have linked the assembly project with the C# project using a DLL file containing the assembly function that contains the logic of the Median Filter.

Now to my question, let's say i have a 7x7 array called table to test the logic

```
TITLE MASM Template(main.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data

table    BYTE  1, 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7
         BYTE  8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
         BYTE  15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21
         BYTE  22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28
         BYTE  29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35
         BYTE  36,37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42
         BYTE  43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49
```

and i want to make a 3x3 window of neighboring pixels around the first index (which is pixel **1**).

```
0 0 0
0 1 2
0 8 9
```

then it would be sorted using any sorting algorithm and take the median value and replace it with the value of the pixel.
then the second window of pixel **2** would be

```
0 0 0
1 2 3
8 9 10
```

how to do that using Irvine x86 assembly language?
how to know the boundaries of the array to put zeroes instead of garbage values?

Comment: In corner you have then `0 0 0 0 0 1 2 8 9` => median 0 ... that's intended? I would rather collapse the box inside boundaries, so the first top left corner would have only 2x2 box consisting of `1 2 8 9` -> sort that, and top 2nd pixel would be 3x2 box `1 2 3 8 9 10`. Or I would run the 3x3 box on the inner (width-2) x (height-2) image, return filtered result with 1px less on each side. ... anyway, "how to know the boundaries using assembly" = like in any other programming language, your question doesn't make much sense, you simply write code which does what you want.

Comment: I don't think the Irvine library has anything that will help you.  It's mostly input/output functions.  You're just processing some data without doing any I/O in your function.

Comment: If you can assume SSE2 as a baseline, it might work well to sort 16 windows in parallel using a sorting network with [`pminub`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/PMINUB_PMINUW) / `pmaxub` as comparators.  It would take 9 XMM registers to use one for each window element, though, so this would be easier in x86-64 mode.  It wouldn't take much shuffling to get data into vector regs: just 3 overlapping unaligned loads from each row.  Of course you'd need extra code to handle the corners and the start/end of each row, and the case where the row width is less than 16 bytes.